# Where are the kernel arguments documented?

Tags: linux, kernel, documentation

I want to read more about the Linux Kernel argument for `memtest`. Where can I find out more information about the arguments my kernel accepts?

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is only one place to find the documentation for kernel arguments and that's in the repo under,

- [Documentation/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.txt](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/92f90cc9fe0e7a984ea3d4bf3d120e30ba8a2118/Documentation/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.txt)

This gets packaged on debian as `linux-doc` which will install it under `/usr/share/doc` and provide a symlink for convenience under

```
/usr/share/doc/linux-doc
```

You can find it

```
find -L /usr/share/doc/linux-doc -wholename '*admin-guide/kernel-parameters*' -and -not -path '*translations*'
```